Store logs and query them to form a report using AWS services
My use case is, I have to generate daily report of the security attacks on my APIs (APIs logics are written in lambda function). For this I am logging the IDs of the attackers and other info from the APIs into cloudwatch, and then daily fetch the logs using different lambda function from cloudwatch and send the report from there, using a cron job.
Now I want to know is there any better and cost effective way to store the logs and fetch them for the report or is it the best way there. Can someone please help me?

you can create athena, and Create DB Query to create your reports.
